# Abstract parent class calls derived class method

Tags: java, inheritance

So I was wondering about how classes instances are built.

```
public abstract class test {

    int count;

    public test(){
        count();
        count();
        System.out.println("test" + this.count);
    }
    abstract void count();
}

public class derive extends test{

    int count;

    public derive(){
        System.out.println("derive");
    }
    @Override
    public void count(){
        count++;
    }
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    derived o = new derived();
}
```

The output is:

test0

derive

How come count = 0? and not 2?

Comment: What you actually want in this scenario is to delete the line `int count;` from `derive`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The superclass constructor is called first.  It calls `count()` twice.  With polymorphism, `count()` in `derive` is called, incrementing `count` to `2`.  What is incremented is the  `count` variable in `derive`, because that what the simple name `count` means in the subclass.  The `count` variable in `test` is *hidden* by the `count` in `derive`.

However, the print statement refers to the `count` in scope in the superclass, which is still `0`.

Note that when the superclass constructor finishes, then the subclass constructor body can finally execute.  This includes giving all instance variables initial values.  Here, even though `count` is already `2`, it is "initialized" to `0` anyway.  So even if you add a print statement in the subclass constructor, you'll still get `0` for `count` there too.

To get a `count` of `2`, remove the `count` in `derive` and change the `count` in `test` to be `protected` or package-private (no access modifier).  This will make `count()` increment the variable `count` in `test`.

Comment: How come count exist in derive, when there is no instance of derive yet?
can you please explain how does it work?

Comment: At the time that the superclass constructor is executing, the memory for the entire object is already allocated, even if it's not initialized yet.  It's accessible through the subclass method, even if it's not a good idea to do so.

Comment: When does the memory of the object is allocated? If I have some classes, and no constructors at all, is there any memory allocation for those classes at runtime? Or are they getting allocated only while calling the superclass constructor?

Comment: Memory for an object is allocated prior to calling the constructor, during evaluation of the `new` operator.  Please see [JLS, Section 12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5).

Answer (score 4):

Because you have two variables named `count`. One that is visible in `test` (but shadowed) by the one that is in `derive`. Remove `int count` from `derive` and mark it `protected` in `test`.

Comment: "shadowed" or "hidden"?

Comment: @Oleksandr Or [masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_resolution_(programming_languages)#Name_masking).

Answer (score 1):

derived count is 2 while test's count always is 0 as what you called `count()` is the derived method instead of test's one.